# C++ triggers __CRTDECL when trying to delete a pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

Hello I am trying to delete inside the destructor the pointers that I am declaring in the private section of my class.

This is my header file

```
class Bunny
{
private:
   string* colour = new string;
   string* name = new string;
   int* age = new int;
   string* sex = new string;
   vector<string> allNames = { "Thor", "Capt. America", "Ironman", "Black Widow", "Spiderman", "Superman", "Ant Man", "Batman", "Flash", "Aquaman" };
   vector<string> allSexs = { "Male", "Female" };
   vector<string> allColours = { "White", "Brown", "Black", "Spotted"};


public:
   Bunny() {};
   Bunny(int age);
   ~Bunny()
   {
       if (sex != NULL)
       {
           delete sex;
       }
   };

   void printBunny();

};
```

What I understand from this code is that when the destructor is called it will check if the sex pointer is pointing to NULL if not delete the pointer inside the instance of the class that is calling the destructor.

Comment: side note: the use of `new` and `delete` is completely unnecessary here as you can use [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) instead. `std::string` will clean itself up you don't need pointers.

Comment: If this is your actual code, you don't need to use pointers for strings or the pointer to int either. It actually makes sense to use an int as it is because iti s 4 bytes compared to the 8 byte pointer size on 64-bit systems. If you need a pointer, try using unique_ptr, it does this all for you.